# SpriteKit - How to fix distortion in Node's animation?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction, sktexture

I have created an animation of various PNGs, but there are various frames that stretch to the border so the node is 'filled'. The animation should look like the GIF that I have created using the same pictures. Does anybody know how to make the animation look like the GIF?

GIF:
    [Gif: Animation should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVGcl.gif)

Actual: Extra slow
    [Actual result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFL9E.gif)

Border:
[Here you can see the border of the physics body that has the same size of the "node's border"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF18u.png)

I have tried to fix the problem by switching the scene.scalemode. Further, I have tried to make the size of the Node dependent on the size of the textures. Neither looked like the GIF.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var player = SKSpriteNode()
var frames : Array = [SKTexture]()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //Color: Placeholder; Size should be size of original frames
    player = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 500,     height: 1000))

    //Physics
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    //Init the frames to the array
    for i in 1...6 {
        frames.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerRunLeft-\(i)"))
    }
//        Tried to make the player size dependent on the image size - didn't work out
//        for i in frames {
//            player.size = i.size()
//        }

    //Attach the action
    let runAction = SKAction.animate(with: frames, timePerFrame: 0.3)
    player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(runAction))

    //Add to scene
    addChild(player)
    }
}
```

​

Comment: Did you try to lower the `timePerFrame`? to 0.1 or 0.01

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. I think the problem is that the size of the Node is not dynamic so swift automatically stretches the image to the bounds. I have added another picture in which you can see the static border.

Comment: The correct way to create an animation is for the images "playerRunLeft-\(i)" to have the same size. SpriteKit stretches the image to the size you gave 500x1000.