# SpriteKit/UIKit - How to set the position of UIView to the position of a Node?

Tags: swift, uiview, sprite-kit, position, constraints

I have created a UIImageView that should have the same position of the associated node but since the coordinates of the UIView do not equal the coordinates of the Node the view is sometimes in the wrong position.

So the question is if there is a method to position the Image in the node and stay there.

[Here you can see the result of the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HZQe.gif)

Thank you in advance.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var player = SKSpriteNode()
var frames : Array = [UIImage]()
var playerView = UIImageView()


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    player = SKSpriteNode(color: .clear , size: CGSize(width: 50,     height: 100))

    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    for i in 1...6 {
        frames.append(UIImage(named: "playerRunLeft-\(i)")!)
        playerView.contentMode = .topLeft
    }

    player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    playerView.animationImages = frames
    playerView.animationDuration = 0.5
    playerView.contentScaleFactor = 6
    playerView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: view.center.x , y: view.center.y)
    playerView.startAnimating()

    addChild(player)
    view.addSubview(playerView)
}
}
```

Comment: playerView.center = view.center instead of frame.origin.

Comment: same result. I have to add that when the node moves the UIImageview should move to the same location

Comment: player.anchorPoint = CGPoint(0,0) or CGPoint(0,1)

Comment: again the same result. I am thinking about setting constraints to the UIImageview that depend on the location of the underlying node but I think there should be an easier way.

Comment: how about `func animate(with textures: [SKTexture], timePerFrame sec: TimeInterval) `. mixing two systems is not common.

Comment: I have tried to use this function but there is no contentMode. Further, the images in Textures are stretched to the same size.  Generally I try to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54466927/10997120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution:

```
let adjustRatioY = -(view.frame.height / scene!.frame.height)*player.position.y - 24
let adjustRatioX = (view.frame.width / scene!.frame.width)*player.position.x - 15

playerView.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + adjustRatioX , y: view.center.y + adjustRatioY )
```

I have used this function and it works perfectly. In case somebody has the same problem: You have to adjust -24 and 15 manually to center the UIImageView so:

```
playerView.center = view.center //(adjust here)
```

Player.position should be (0/0) for the adjustment.

Comment: You’re brilliant!